# PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute error when all modules are loaded

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

I have request handler:

```
@app.route('/autofavoritetweet/')
def autofavoritetweet():
  deferred.defer(autofavoritetweettask,twaccount_db.key,_countdown=random.randint(0,60),_retry_options=options)
```

the method passed to task queue is

```
def autofavoritetweettask(twaccount_db_key):
   api.create_favorite()
```

This works fine, but sometimes I got this error:

```
X-Appengine-Taskretrycount:0, X-Appengine-Tasketa:1533673734.18604, X-Appengine-Current-Namespace:, X-Appengine-Taskname:72761135380882302641, X-Appengine-Taskexecutioncount:0, X-Appengine-Queuename:default, X-Appengine-Country:ZZ (X-Appengine-Taskretrycount: /base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py:311)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.460 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.extra". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:249)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.466 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.smart_strong". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.467 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.smart_strong.SmartEmphasisExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.498 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.fenced_code". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.498 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.fenced_code.FencedCodeExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.510 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.footnotes". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.510 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.footnotes.FootnoteExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.528 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.attr_list". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.528 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.attr_list.AttrListExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.536 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.def_list". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.536 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.def_list.DefListExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.545 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.tables". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.545 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.tables.TableExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.552 JST
Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.abbr". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:233)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.552 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.abbr.AbbrExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
2018-08-08 05:28:58.553 JST
Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.extra.ExtraExtension". (lib.zip/markdown/__init__.py:190)
Permanent failure attempting to execute task (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py:327)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 318, in post
    self.run_from_request()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 313, in run_from_request
    run(self.request.body)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 153, in run
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'admin_required'
```

Why sometimes it works, sometime it does not?
My code does not have anything related to `admin_required`, so I can not figured out what is happening.

From Google document

> ```
> You can't pass a method defined in the request handler module.
> ```
>
> The last point above deserves special attention: passing a method
>   defined in the request handler module - the module specified as a
>   request handler in app.yaml - will not work. You can call
>   deferred.defer from the request handler module, but the function you
>   are passing to it must be defined elsewhere!

so passing method `autofavoritetweettask` to `autofavoritetweet` does not work? 
but then why it works most of the time:
[image: check log screen capture]

the error just comes when modules are loaded. 
I do not understand why sometimes all modules are loaded in task queue, but sometimes not.

Thank you.
UPDATE 1: Admin_require is

```
def admin_required(f):
  decorator_order_guard(f, 'auth.admin_required')

  @functools.wraps(f)
  def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
    if is_logged_in() and current_user_db().admin:
      return f(*args, **kwargs)
    if not is_logged_in() and flask.request.path.startswith('/api/'):
      return flask.abort(401)
    if not is_logged_in():
      return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('signin', next=flask.request.url))
    return flask.abort(403)

  return decorated_function
```

Comment: It could be due to improper python path manipulation. Please check the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred#handling-import-path-manipulation) and try the workaround mentioned. You can check also [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/25) thread where somehow similar issue to yours has been addressed. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: hi, i check it. But admin_require is a function that I wrote myself. It is not a module that I import from somewhere. I updated my question with admin_require function

Comment: i think i know the issue now. it seems markdown module is trying to load all of extension and it can not find admin_require. it is the markdown problem.

Comment: Please share your solution and post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: deferred request is the first request to hit an instance, so it can not find admin_required. But I do not use admin_required at all. I dont understand why deferred request need admin_required.

Comment: I suggest you to look in the code of [deferred.py](https://github.com/optimizely/python-appengine/blob/master/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py) at the line where error is thrown and try to debug why the `admin_required` gets picked.